# Error opening downloaded file (image, excel, etc) Laravel/Vuetify app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Laravel 5.7 and Vuetify. I coded the methods to download a file stored in laravel folder (image, word file, excel file, pdf file,...); the app dowload it properly, but when I open the file, it shows error (except for PDF files, PDF files work perfectly):
[image: image error]

Here is my code:

Backend

```
public function downloadFile()
{
    $url = Input::get('url');
    return response()->download(storage_path($url));
}
```

Frontend

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headersT"
  :items="data"
  :loading="tableLoading"
  :total-items="data.length"
  hide-actions
  class="elevation-1">
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
   <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
   <td>
    <v-btn
      fab
      dark
      small
      color="white"
      slot="activator"
      @click="download(props.item.url)"
     >
      <v-icon color="accent">image_search</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
    </td>   
</v-data-table>
```

...

```
methods: {
      download (file) {
        this.axios.get('downloadfile?url=' + file)
          .then((response) => {
            let urls = file
            let lastPosition = urls.lastIndexOf('/')
            let nameFile = urls.substr(lastPosition + 1, urls.length)
            let dot = urls.lastIndexOf('.')
            let extension = urls.substr(dot + 1, urls.length)
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
            const link = document.createElement('a')
            link.href = url
            link.setAttribute('download', nameFile) // or any other extension
            document.body.appendChild(link)
            link.click()
          })
          .catch(e => {
            this.$store.commit(SNACK_SHOW, {msg: 'Error in process.', color: 'danger'})
            return false
          })
        }
      }
},
```

It is some part of the data in Chrome console:
[image]

Comment: Does the image works when you open them directly in the folder ? Also; `storage_path($url)` looks risky. What if the user request `/framework/[...]` ? I don't recall if `storage_path()` accept path traversal `storage_path("../../../etc/passwd")` I don't think so, but it would be very open door.

Comment: Yes Clément Baconnier , the image works when I open it directly in the folder.... Thanks for the security advice, I will have it in mind.